# Cookie not sent with HTTP Request

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, router, httpcookie

I am building a Forum App using Java SpringBoot as Backend, ReactJS as Frontend. Layman as I am,please bear with any of my ignorance.

Both front & backend are deployed on Heroku, DNS managed by Cloudflare.

**Expectation**
I was expecting that when entering,say, /forum/opinion/1, the initial writer could Edit/Delete, but now I myself cannot even enter the OpinionBoard, because the server cannot seem to receive my token.

**Issues:**
Now I keep facing this Java Error when entering any of my opinionController's endpoints: **Required cookie 'loginToken' for method parameter type String is not present**
So I **guess** that my cookies cannot be sent along with HTTP requests from frontend.

Because the JWT tokens can be successfully sent as HTTP response from backend and stored in the browser(when I type 'document.cookie', there are the cookies I sent), but the cookies cannot be sent along back with frontend requests.

**Tried**
I have tried adding `{withCredentials:true}` or
`const headers = {     Authorization:` Bearer ${loginToken}`, };`
, but the error remains the same. So there must have been something I oversighted.

Any help or guidance is appreciated! :) And if any detail is needed, please let me know!

Below are my codes and logs.

**the log**

```
stasy@Stasys-Air public-privacy-backend %  heroku logs --tail --app public-privacy  

2023-08-03T09:16:02.261550+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03T09:16:02.261Z DEBUG 2 --- [io-16059-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-08-03T09:16:02.264739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/collaborator/dashboard" host=api.public-privacy.xyz request_id=9fe4e289-ad11-4f8f-b90c-f3b608fa18de fwd="106.105.197.9,172.68.106.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=4564 protocol=http
2023-08-03T09:20:31.613264+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03T09:20:31.613Z DEBUG 2 --- [io-16059-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/forum/opinions/1", parameters={}
2023-08-03T09:20:31.613741+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03T09:20:31.613Z DEBUG 2 --- [io-16059-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.Stasy.PublicPrivacyAppBackendHeroku.controller.OpinionsController#readOpinion(String, Integer, HttpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest)
2023-08-03T09:20:31.614770+00:00 app[web.1]: 2023-08-03T09:20:31.614Z DEBUG 2 --- [io-16059-exec-7] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.Stasy.PublicPrivacyAppBackendHeroku.controller.OpinionsController.readOpinion(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws org.Stasy.PublicPrivacyAppBackendHeroku.exception.UserNotFoundException: Required cookie 'loginToken' for method parameter type String is not present
```

**My Backend Code**:

**2. OpinionsController.java**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/forum")
public class OpinionsController {

    private final JwtGenerator jwtGenerator;
    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;
    private final UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
    private final OpinionsRepository opinionsRepository;

    @Autowired
    //constructor
    public OpinionsController(JwtGenerator jwtGenerator, JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl, OpinionsRepository opinionsRepository) {
        this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
        this.userServiceImpl = userServiceImpl;
        this.opinionsRepository = opinionsRepository;
    }

    //view all opinions
    @GetMapping("/opinions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> readOpinions(@CookieValue(name = "loginToken", required = true) String loginToken, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws UserNotFoundException {

        boolean is200=false;
        boolean is403=false;
        boolean is500=false;
        try {
            String email = jwtDecoder.decodeUserEmailFromLoginToken(loginToken);
            User user = userServiceImpl.findUserByEmail(email);

            if(!Objects.equals(user,null) && !Objects.equals(email,null)){
                is200=true;
            }
        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            is403=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            is200=false;
            e.printStackTrace();
            //return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Collections.emptyList());
        }finally {
            if(is200==true){
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "loginToken");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "dashboardToken");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("loginToken", loginToken);
                response.addCookie(cookie);

                return new ResponseEntity<List<Opinion>>(opinionsRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }else if(is403){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("The Collaborator doesn't exist in the Database. Please contact us.");
            }else{
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(Collections.emptyList());
            }
        }
    }

    //read an opinion by ID
    //public ResponseEntity<Opinion> readOpinion(@PathVariable Long id){
    @GetMapping("/opinions/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> readOpinion(@CookieValue(name = "loginToken", required = true) String loginToken, @PathVariable Integer id, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws UserNotFoundException {

        Opinion opinion = opinionsRepository.findOpinionById(id);//this is the step where data loads. in put method)this cannot be directly reflected upon deleting. I can still fetch ID.
        boolean is200 = false;
        boolean is500 = false;
        boolean is204 = false;//deleted

        try {
            if (Objects.equals(opinion, null)) {
                is204 = true;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("A NullPointerException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            //verify if the data is really there
            if (!Objects.equals(id, null)) {
                String email = jwtDecoder.decodeUserEmailFromLoginToken(loginToken);
                is200 = true;
               // return new ResponseEntity<Opinion>(opinionsRepository.findOpinionById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                is204 = true;
                return new ResponseEntity<String>("This opinion was deleted.", HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            is500 = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is204) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body("Sorry,the content is deleted.");  ///Debug
            } else if (is500) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build(); //500
            }  else if (is200) {
                if (!Objects.equals(id, null)) {
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS");
                    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept");
                    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "loginToken");
                    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "dashboardToken");
                    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("loginToken", loginToken);
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                    return new ResponseEntity<Opinion>(opinionsRepository.save(opinion), HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    //C==> create an opinion
    @PostMapping(value = "/opinions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createOpinions(@RequestBody Opinion opinion, HttpServletResponse response) {
        boolean is201=false;
        boolean is205=false;
        User user=null;
        try {
            String collaboratorName=opinion.getCollaboratorName();
            user=userServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(collaboratorName);
            Opinion savedOpinion = opinionsRepository.save(opinion);
            System.out.println(savedOpinion);
            is201=true;
            System.out.println("Java 3, edit an opinion from PostMapping/opinions");
            System.out.println("Opinion Data before processing :" + savedOpinion.toString());//this is where things might go wrong

        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            is201=false;
            is205=true;
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.RESET_CONTENT);//205==>when to new, and when to not new?
        }finally {
            if(is201){
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "loginToken");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "dashboardToken");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

                //add cookie now
                String dashboardToken = jwtGenerator.generateDashboardToken(user);
                Cookie Cookie=new Cookie("dashboardToken",dashboardToken);
                System.out.println("dashboardToken:"+dashboardToken);
                Cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                Cookie.setMaxAge(3600); //an hour
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.addCookie(Cookie);

                //add login cookie too
                String loginToken=null;
                try {
                    loginToken = jwtGenerator.generateLoginToken(user);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("loginToken", loginToken);
                System.out.println("Hi, this loginToken is printing from UserController:" + loginToken);
                loginCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                loginCookie.setMaxAge(3600); //an hour
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.addCookie(loginCookie);

                return new ResponseEntity<String>(dashboardToken, HttpStatus.CREATED); //201
            }else if(is205){
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.RESET_CONTENT);//205
            }else{
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);//500
            }
        }
    }

    //Update==>edit

    @PutMapping("/opinions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateOpinion(@RequestBody Opinion opinion, @CookieValue(name = "dashboardToken", required = true) String dashboardToken, HttpServletResponse response) throws UserNotFoundException
    {
        boolean is200=false;
        boolean is205=false;
        boolean is403=true;
        boolean is500=false;
        String username1=null;

        System.out.println("opinion.toString()");
        System.out.println(opinion.toString());

        try{
            username1 = jwtDecoder.decodeUserInfoFromDashboardToken(dashboardToken);
            Opinion existingOpinion = opinionsRepository.findOpinionById(opinion.getId());
            String username2 = existingOpinion.getCollaboratorName();//是用Opinion的ID找

            if(!userServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(username1).isEnabled() || !userServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(username2).isEnabled()){
                is403=false;
            }
            if (username1.equals(username2)) {
                is403=false;
            }
            if(Objects.equals(opinion, null)){
                is205=true;
            }

            is200=true;
            opinionsRepository.save(opinion);

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "loginToken");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "dashboardToken");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            //add Token as cookie
            User user = userServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(username1);
            String loginToken=null;
            try {
                loginToken = jwtGenerator.generateLoginToken(user);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("loginToken", loginToken);
            loginCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            loginCookie.setMaxAge(3600); //an hour
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.addCookie(loginCookie);

            Cookie dashboardCookie = new Cookie("dashboardToken", dashboardToken);
            dashboardCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            dashboardCookie.setMaxAge(3600); //an hour
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.addCookie(dashboardCookie);

        }catch (Exception e){
            is500=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }finally {
            if(is403){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("Only the initial author is able to modify the content.");
            }else if(is205){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.RESET_CONTENT).body("Please reset the content");
            }else if(is500){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
            }else if(is200){
                return new ResponseEntity<List<Opinion>>(opinionsRepository.findOpinionByCollaboratorName(username1),HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        }
    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**
This is my WebConfig:(I know it could have been more concise, any suggestion welcome!)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       
        registry.addMapping("/forum/opinions/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("https://public-privacy.xyz")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Authorization","Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders("loginToken")
                .exposedHeaders("dashboardToken")
                .maxAge(3600);

        registry.addMapping("/forum/opinions/**")
                .allowedOrigins("https://public-privacy.xyz") // Update from allowedOriginPatterns to allowedOrigins
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders("loginToken", "dashboardToken")
                .maxAge(3600);


        registry.addMapping("/forum/opinions/add")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("https://public-privacy.xyz")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Authorization","Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders("loginToken")
                .exposedHeaders("dashboardToken")
                .maxAge(3600);

        registry.addMapping("/forum/opinions/edit/{id}")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("https://public-privacy.xyz")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS","PUT")
                .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept","Authorization","Cookie")
                .exposedHeaders("loginToken")
                .exposedHeaders("dashboardToken")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

**My frontend code**

**1. http-common.js:**

```
import axios from "axios"; 

export default axios.create({
    //
    baseURL:"https://api.public-privacy.xyz",

    headers:{
      "Cocntent-type":"application/json",
    },
    withCredentials:true
    
})
```

**2.AddOpinion.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from "./shared/AuthContext.js";
import httpClient from "../http-common.js";
import '../../src/App.css';
import Footer from "../components/Footer.js";

const AddOpinion = () => {

  ////attributes 

  const { userInfo,loginToken,dashboardToken } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [collaboratorName, setCollaboratorName] = useState('');
  const [body, setBody] = useState('');
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('gender equality');
  const [createdAt, setCreatedAt] = useState('');
  const [updatedAt, setUpdatedAt] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [remainingWords, setRemainingWords] = useState(501);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update remaining words count whenever the body changes
    setRemainingWords(501 - body.trim().split(/\s+/).length);
  }, [body]);

  ////functions
  useEffect(() => {

      setCollaboratorName(userInfo?.sub);

      const get = (id) => {
      
        const response=httpClient.get(`/forum/opinions/${id}`);
        return response;
        //////////////////////
      };

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          if (id) {
            ////
            console.log(`Is this where put method goes through 4?`);
            //////
            const response = await get(id);
            const opinion = response.data;
            setTitle(opinion.title);
            setBody(opinion.body);
            setCategory(opinion.category);
            setCreatedAt(opinion.createdAt);
            setUpdatedAt(opinion.updatedAt);
            setCollaboratorName(opinion.CollaboratorName);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           ////
          console.log(`Is this where put method goes through 3?`);
           //////
          console.log(userInfo);
          console.log('Something went wrong', error);
        }
      };

      fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  const create = (data) => {
    console.log(`data in create method`);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("data in create");
    console.log(data);
    return httpClient.post("/forum/opinions", data, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  };

  //Update
  const update = (data) => {
     ////
    console.log(`Is this where put method goes through 1 ?`);
     //////
    console.log(`update method in Addopinion`);
    console.log(`data in update method in AddOpinion`);
    console.log(data);
    navigate(`/forum/opinions/edit/${id}`);

    return httpClient.put('/forum/opinions', data, {
        withCredentials: true, 
  });}


  //this is Mr. Button himself 
const saveOpinion = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (!title || !body) {
      setErrors(true);
      return;
    }

    let opinion = {
      title,
      body,
      category,
      id,
      collaboratorName: userInfo?.username,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt
    };

  if(id){
  console.log(`Is this where put method goes through 2 ?`);
  console.log("opinion before update:");
  console.log(opinion);
  update(opinion)
      .then(response => {
          if(response.status===200){
            alert(`updated successfully!`);
            navigate("/forum/opinions");
          }
          else if(response.status===205){
           alert(`updated successfully!`);
            navigate("/forum/opinions");
          }else if(response.status===400){
            alert(`Oops! Something went wrong. Come back later`);
             navigate("/forum/opinions");
           }
          console.log("Opinion updated sucessfully");
          console.log("response.data");
          console.log(response?.data);
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log("error", error);
        if(error===403){
          alert(`${error}`);
          alert(`Oops! not authorized to modify the content!`);
          navigate("/forum/opinions");
        }else {
          alert(`${error}`);
          alert(`Apologies. Server-side issues. We'll fix it asap.`);
          navigate("/forum/opinions");
        }
    })
  }else
  {
    console.log("opinion before create:"+opinion);
    create(opinion)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 201) {
        alert(`Opinion shared successfully!`);
        navigate("/forum/opinions");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert(`${error}`);
      alert(`Apologies. Server-side issues. We'll fix it asap.`);
      navigate("/forum/opinions");
    });
}};
```